# Angular 2 with SharePoint 2013 web part development

Tags: database, rest, angular, sharepoint-2013, farm-solution

I want to develop web part for SharePoint 2013 farm solution using WCF custom Rest Services that will get data from content database using server object model and to consume those services in web part I have to use Angular 2. Can anyone tell me how to use Angular 2 in share point 2013 for web part development.

Answer (score 0):

Here have a example for what you need.

http://mahedee.net/introduction-to-angularjs-and-bootstrap-in-asp-net-web-form/

Look, it is simple to do.

Your web part is a custom ASP.NET WebForms for SharePoint.
Add angular libraries and your custom logic, like your angular controllers, services, factorie in your MasterPage and in your Index.aspx add angular directive what you need.

Comment: Thank you but I was looking for some example or tutorial or steps in SharePoint to do this  via demonstration